# node.js - how to access home folder when running as a daemon (using node-mac) OSX

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js

need to access files in the user home directory with a node.js script.

this works fine when run in terminal:

```
function getUserHome() {return process.env.HOME;}
var home = getUserHome();
```

however - when run as a daemon (created by node-mac) getUserHome returns 'undefined'

any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `__dirname` or `__filename`

Comment: aha - that could work.  thanks

Comment: Obviously `HOME` environment variable is not set when you run your [tag:node.js] app as a daemon. BTW what is the **uid** of the **node** process? (`process.getuid()`). Is it same as the user id you want to get their home directory? (run `id` on **Terminal**)

Comment: @fardjad - thanks - i didn't know that actually.  adeneo's idea worked perfectly.

Comment: @drkoss until you move the script out of the home directory :)